# Supporting Multiple Jira Instances in Gerrit

Tags: jira, gerrit, jira-plugin

Has anyone had experience supporting multiple Jira instances in Gerrit? Right now my current setup points to one Jira Instance, but we are in the process of migrating to a new Jira instance and will need to support both in one Gerrit Server.

Currently we have a commentlink configured in the `gerrit.config`:

```
[commentlink "changeid"]
  match = (I[0-9a-f]{8,40})
  link = "#q,$1,n,z"

[commentlink "jira"]
  match = ([a-zA-Z]+-\\d+):
  link = https://jira.url.com/browse/$1
```

I was wondering if I needed to add a second. Also I have the jira hook plugin, wasn't sure if I needed an additional plugin. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nothing to do with Jira in particular. Basically it says if a comment has "XXX-123" then replace the text with a link. How do you think it may know which link it should use?

Comment: Updated the question with how thats handled. Wasn't sure that was really necessary in this case but wanted to add it in.

Comment: Could you tell how a human would understand which jira instance should be used for a particular jira issue number?

Comment: A person would push there change to Gerrit. The push would have a commit id in the message `git commit -m "<Proj>-<Issue Number>: Name of the issue" then when you do a push, the commit is parsed and a comment is applied to the jira issue with the push.

Comment: Ok, how would human know that ABC-123 is a first jira instance, but ABD-123 is a second instance? Moreover, it could be ambiguous, e.g. nothing stops to have TEST-1 in both jiras.

Comment: We have a script called comment-added that has the projects name for the second jira instance hard coded in, so when the change ID has a projct that should goto the second jira instance it gets routed there

Comment: I'm wondering if for the gerrit integration I need to install a second jira plugin for the second jira instance comment link

Comment: What is a "jira plugin"?

Comment: Like hook-jira plugin.

Comment: Yes, apparently for Jira connectivity you should have several instances of the plugin, but anyway, you need different "match" regexps to separate commentlink sections.

Comment: Ok thanks, what do you mean by "several instances of the plugin"? Is that just adding another comment link as you have in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

So just hardcode the project names such as:

```
[commentlink "jira1"]
  match = ((PRJA|PRJB|PRJC|PRJD)-\\d+):
  link = https://jira1.url.com/browse/$1

[commentlink "jira2"]
  match = ([a-zA-Z]+-\\d+):
  link = https://jira2.url.com/browse/$1
```